# Split value from textarea by line break and add text indent to each of them (Javascript)

Tags: javascript, html, split

I am spliting the  value from textarea by line break and add `text indent` to each of them.

Here is my code:

```js
function splits() {
  let textarea = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0]
  let arrays = textarea.value.split(/\r?\n/)
  for (let i = 0; i < arrays.length; i++) {
    textarea.style.textIndent = "10px"
    textarea.value = "<p>" + arrays[i] + "</p>"
    //not working return "<p>(The content I entered)</p>
  }
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
<button onclick=splits()>Splits</button>
```

I want to make each of the  elements from the arrays be in a new `<p>`.

However, my code above is obviously not working.

Do anyone know anyone to do this?

Thanks for any helps and responds.

Comment: You're replacing the textarea value each time through the loop, not appending to it.

Comment: if you add a return there it will exit the entire function, so at `i === 0` the function will end. also what @Barmar said above. you can either append to the textArea like Barmar suggests, or you can replace the value in `arrays[i]` with the new one with the p tags (`arrays[i] = "<p>" + arrays[i] + "</p>"`). then at the end do `textarea.value = arrays.join()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not possible to do with a textarea. What you are looking for is an content editable div

```js
function splits(){
  const div = document.getElementById("test");
  let values = div.innerText.split(/\r?\n/)
  div.innerHTML = values.map(sentence => `<p>${sentence}</p>`).join("");
  div.style.textIndent = "10px";
}
```

```css
div#test {
    width: 300px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
}
```

```html
<div contenteditable="true" id="test"></div>
<button onclick=splits()>Splits</button>
```

Comment: Wow, that is another very helpful answer.

Answer (score 2):

You're replacing the textarea value each time through the loop, rather than appending to it.

You also don't need to set the style each time through the loop, you can do that just once.

```js
function splits() {
  let textarea = document.getElementsByTagName("textarea")[0]
  let arrays = textarea.value.split(/\r?\n/)
  textarea.style.textIndent = "10px"
  textarea.value = arrays.map(s => `<p>${s}</p>`).join("");
}
```

```html
<textarea></textarea>
<button onclick=splits()>Splits</button>
```

Comment: The content is between <p></p>  every time and it seems likes is not changing the elements to a paragraphy tag.

Comment: The value of a textarea is text, it's not parsed as HTML.

Comment: So i can't add HTML codes to textarea, can I?

Comment: No, you can't. The value is what the user has entered into the textarea. They don't type HTML codes.

Comment: I think you misunderstand my meaning. I want to add `text-indent` to every line break. But the text-indent only works for elements. So i split the value by line break and make the each of the value to become a new `<p>` so that each of them will have `text-indent`.

Comment: You can't treat the contents of a textarea as HTML. You can't add styling to different parts of it.

Comment: So do you know a way how to make the value indented after every line break. 

Comment: Add spaces after the newline